# Can't Convert NSNamedColorSpace to NSDeviceRGBColorSpace?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Can anyone tell me why this `colorUsingColorSpaceName` is returning `nil`? For example, the following code block will print "deviceColor is nill":

```
NSColor *color = [NSColor windowBackgroundColor];
NSColor *deviceColor = [color colorUsingColorSpaceName: NSDeviceRGBColorSpace];
if(deviceColor == nil) NSLog(@"deviceColor is nill");
```

How can I convert an `NSColor` in the `NSNamedColorSpace`? I need to be able to get the color components so i can convert an `NSColor` to a `CGColorRef`

Answer (score 6):

It's too complicated to be expressed as an RGB value.  It's a single object that draws differently when the window is active vs inactive.  In some cases it's also a pattern color (i.e. a tiled image) rather than a flat fill.

Comment: So how am I supposed to get the right colors for drawing custom ui components with Core Graphics?

Comment: Bret: Use `[NSColor windowBackgroundColor]`. To make a CGColor for it, try this: Get its `patternImage` (and go the RGB-conversion route if it doesn't have one), create a CGImage from the NSImage, create a CGPattern that draws the CGImage, and create a CGColor with that CGPattern.